# Read Local CSV file into a 2D Array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, csv, multidimensional-array

Hoping I could get some help with reading a csv file into a 2d array for a node app.

I've seen other questions with answers which suggest papaparse, jquery-csv, and csv npm packages. I have read the documentation for each of those solutions and do not see where in the process would my program read the csv.

I have a csv file in my documents folder: C:\Documents\Folder\data.csv for example.

I was hoping I could have the program read the data.csv which is formatted like so

```
header0 header1 header2 header3 header4 header5 header6 header7 header8 header9   
data    data    data    data    data    data    data    data    data    data   
data    data    data    data    data    data    data    data    data    data
```

and place it into an array called myarray

myarray[0][9] would give me header9 and so on.

Here is what I have when I tried jquery-csv

```
var fs = require('fs');
var csv = require('./jquery.csv.js');
var sample = 'C:\Documents\Folder\data.csv';

var myarray = $.csv.toArrays(sample);
```

The error I receive is

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\0121160\Documents\Nodejs\readcsv.js:7:14)
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11[39m
```

note: I have very minimal experience with javascript, node, jquery.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` means that it doesn't know what you're calling with $. That's basically jQuery, but it doesn't come built in so you will need to define it for your document before you can start using its methods. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869467/jquery-is-undefined

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery ...

To include jQuery in Node, first install with npm.

`npm install jquery`

For jQuery to work in Node, a window with a document is required. Since no such window exists natively in Node, one can be mocked by tools such as jsdom. This can be useful for testing purposes.

```
require("jsdom").env("", function(err, window) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }

    var $ = require("jquery")(window);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says `$ is not defined`, so you need to use `var myarray = csv.toArrays(sample);`.

The variable `$` does not mean anything to your program as you haven't imported anything that's assigned to the variable `$`.

I also doubt `var csv = require('./jquery.csv.js');` will work, you'll probably have to `npm install jquery-csv` and then import `var csv = require('jquery-csv')` into your module.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is designed for helping do common things with JavaScript embedded on a webpage. jQuery CSV is a plugin for it.

Since you are writing software to run on Node.js and not in a webpage, jQuery isn't a great choice of library… so don't use it or a plugin for it.

Get a CSV parser optimised for Node.js such as [csv-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('csv-parser')

const path = 'C:/Documents/Folder/data.csv';
const results = [];

fs.createReadStream(path)
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log(results);
  });
```

Comment: Quentin thanks for your solution! I got the csv-parser to place my data.csv into the results array.However, when I tried to read only a certain element such as results[0][9]. It comes back as undefined. @Quentin.

Comment: I utilized Quentins suggestion using csv-parser. It worked to a certain extent. When the code finishes executing I am left with an array that has only 2 items in the array. I can call results[0], and results[1]. results [0] returns all the headers and all the matching data from the csv. That is great, but I was hoping to call each individual cell by utilizing results[1][2] or results[2][7] etc....